# EclipseLink New L2 Cache

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

How to create my own implementation of EclipseLink's L2 cache?

My current issue is that I want to be able to use memcache/redis as a distributed cache, but currently I can't find any way of doing this. Most of the solutions I found is about cache coordination which seems a bit overkill for my requirement. I just need shared L2 cache across horizontally scaled servers.

Thanks

Comment: cache coordination is for syncing in-memory cache that eclipselink is using by default,
writing your own stuff when its provides something is overkill, what are you trying to do exactly?